# How to integrate WalletConnect in your Dapp using web3-react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ethereum, web3-react

I've been trying to integrate [WalletConnect](https://walletconnect.org/) by following this [documentation](https://github.com/NoahZinsmeister/web3-react/blob/v6/docs/connectors/walletconnect.md) of [web3-react](https://github.com/NoahZinsmeister/web3-react).

The configuration that I'm using for the connector is as follows:

```js
import { WalletConnectConnector } from '@web3-react/walletconnect-connector';

export const walletconnect = new WalletConnectConnector({
  rpc: { 1: RPC_URLS[1], 4: RPC_URLS[4] },
  infuraId: INFURA_TOKEN,
  bridge: BRIDGE_URL,
  qrcode: true,
  pollingInterval: 15000,
});
```

Also, the versions of packages are as follows:

```json
"@web3-react/core": "^6.0.9",
"@web3-react/walletconnect-connector": "^6.2.0",
```

When I use the `activate` function from `useWeb3React()` as explained in below code:

```js
const { connector, activate, active, account } = useWeb3React();
```

```js
activate(walletconnect, undefined, true)
    .catch((error) => {
        if (error instanceof UnsupportedChainIdError) {
            activate(walletconnect)
        } else {
            console.log('Pending Error Occured')
        }
    })
```

It was able to generate QR Code, also I was able to successfully scan through MetaMask app on my Mobile Phone and on the mobile app it shows successfully connected.

Though, on the console logs of the Web App it shows a warning saying

```js
Warning: Suppressed stale connector activation [object Object]
```

Thus, It fails to receive address inside the `account` variable.

**Important Note:** I'm using the similar code with `InjectedConnector` and it is working **perfectly fine for MetaMask**.

Though the above problem also appears with other wallets.
These are the wallets I am facing the problem with:

1. [WalletConnect](https://github.com/NoahZinsmeister/web3-react/blob/v6/docs/connectors/walletconnect.md)
2. [WalletLink (Coinbase Wallet)](https://github.com/NoahZinsmeister/web3-react/blob/v6/docs/connectors/walletlink.md)
3. [Portis](https://github.com/NoahZinsmeister/web3-react/blob/v6/docs/connectors/portis.md)

Answer (score 2):

I solved it in two ways:

1. Calling the activate function multiple times in subsequent lines
2. Setting a delay on calling the activate function, something like this

   ```
   setTimeout(() => activate(...), 500)
   ```

I'm not sure about your code structure so I don't know to what extend this helps. But stale connector object issue is something that I have resolved using the above two methods.